# How to quickly choose a number in a wide range and avoiding prohibited numbers

Tags: algorithm, random

I am making a snake game and I need to place an apple in the x*y map in each loop, this apple cannot be placed on the body of the snake

My code probably looks like this

```
// snake_body is a array include all body's coordinate
snake_body := []

// Find coordinates in a loop that are not in the snake_body
function setApple()
    loop
        apple_x := random(map_x)
        apple_x := random(map_y)
        if not apple_x, apple_y in snake_body
            return apple_x, apple_y
```

This is a poor design that gives quick results when the snake is relatively short, but once you get into the late game and the snake's body takes up most of the coordinates, the loop needs to be executed very many times to find valid coordinates

My current solution is to also create and maintain a coordinate array that is not used by the snake

```
empty_ground := []

function refresh()
    // Use this method in each loop to update the elements in the empty ground

function setApple()
    return random(empty_ground)
```

This would require me to maintain a large coordinate table, and updating it would also require some arithmetic power, and I would like to know if there is any better algorithm that can solve this problem quickly?

Comment: You could have a mix of both methods. If the snake's size is less than 75% of the total number of pixel, use your current loop. If the snake's size is more than 75% of the total number of pixels, then keep a set of all the empty pixels (as described in MrSmith42 's answer)

Comment: How _large_ can the grid get?

Comment: **would require me to maintain a very large coordinate table"* - Is that a problem?

Comment: Shouldn't there be `apple_y`?

Answer (score 2):

**Fast but memory consuming:**
I would keep a `Set` of all empty cells. when the snake moves a cell, remove the cell newly occupied by the head from the Ste and add the cell released by the tail to the Set. Than simply take `rand(sizeOfEmptyCellsSet)` and place an apple at the location related to the `rand(sizeOfEmptyCellsSet)th` element of the `Set`.
*(The Set will take more memory than the grid, if a lot of empty cells exist)*

**Slow but for reasonable grid size fast enough:**
Keep only track of how many empty cells there are, take `rand(numberOfEmptyCells)` and tan iterate your grid until you passed that many empty cells. Than place your apple on the next empty cell.

Comment: *"Than simply take rand(sizeOfEmptyCellsSet) and place an apple at this location."* - How is rand(sizeOfEmptyCellsSet) a location?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy; It's the number of the element in the set where you put the apple.  I fixed the sloppy description in the answer for a more specific one

Comment: How do you efficiently get the i-th element of a set? I don't think set data types typically support that.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy; Sets are often `Iterable` or even allow access to ith element. Or implement your own Set which has this feature.

Comment: And that's efficient/quick?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy: can be done in `O(1)`

Comment: Sure, it *can* be done. But *is* it done by typical sets? I don't think so. So that would be something to at least mention in the answer.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy: Variation of a HashSet will do it in O(1). I wonder how big your grid is that this is of any concern.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do what you want efficiently, but probably the easiest way is like this:

- Use a numbering system for your cells, so cell (x,y) has number y*width + x
- Make a list of available cell numbers.  Call it `available`.  This should be initally populated with all cell numbers in any order.
- Make another list `avpos` that gives the position of each available cell in `available`, i.e., if a cell number `i`i is available, then we have `available[avpos[i]] == i`

To place an apple, just randomly select a cell from the `available` list.

To make a cell `i` unavailable:

- If `i` is the last item in `available`, then just remove it
- Otherwise, remove the last item from `available` (call it `last`) and set `available[avpos[i]] = last`.  Then fix up `avpos`: `avpos[last] = avpos[i]`

To make a cell `i` available:

- set `avpos[i] = len(available)`
- append `i` to the `available` list

If you need to check to see if a cell `i` is available: `avpos[i] >= 0 && avpos[i] < len(available) && available[avpos[i]] == i`

After the initial setup, all operations are constant time.  This requires only two board-sized arrays of integers, which seems to be a reasonable cost for a snake game.  If you want to save some memory, you can also use `avpos` to store the whole board state (with negative numbers for types of unavailable cells).

Comment: How do you make a cell available again? And I don't see the point in randomizing beforehand. Just pick a random `available` element each time you want one.

Comment: Making a cell available again is not in the requirements, but it's not hard -- just append it to `available` and fix up `avpos`.   Yes you can select a random element when you want one, but then you have to swap it with the end and fix up `avpos`.  The description was simpler with the randomization up front.

Comment: Making a cell *unavailable* also isn't explicitly in the requirements, is it? And "just append it" is no good. Then that would be the next apple position, so that wouldn't be random. You could *insert* it at a random position (moving the current occupant to the end), but then you'd have randomization at two places, and making a cell available and unavailable would both need thay swapping. If instead you pick a random one when needed, you need randomization only once, and you *can* just append to make a cell available.

Comment: Making a cell unavailable is what you do when the snake occupies that cell.  W.r.t inserting at the end... yes, that's correct.

Comment: And making a cell available is what you do when the snake tail leaves that cell.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that the snakes tail doesn't move, but I suppose that wasn't specified.

Comment: Hmm, I think it's famous enough that that doesn't need to be specified. There's an animation on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_%28video_game_genre%29) in case you never played it.

Comment: Oh, *that* snake game.  Yes, I made edits

Comment: Is there another that fits the question? I found two other similar snake games now, but one is a puzzle game where the apples don't seem to be random and the other doesn't even have a grid.